# Fluent API Association mapping, without navigation EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6

We have the following table structure

```
Person
--ID  (PK)
--NAME

Bank Account 
   P_ID (FK - Person.ID)
   Name
   Number



RichPerson
   P_ID (FK - Person.ID
   Age  
   ..other fields

   (primary key (P_ID, Age)
```

What we are trying to achieve is to load the bank accounts for RichPerson
i.e.

```
 class RichPerson
{
           public int P_ID {get;set;}
           public int Age  {get;set;}
           public List<BankAccount> accounts;

 }


 class Person {
           public int ID {get; set;}
           public string Name {get;set;}
}

 class BankAccount {
           public int P_ID {get;set;}
           public string Name {get; set;}
           public int Number {get;set;}
           /* No navigation property is a requirement */
}
```

We have tried various options but cant figure out the association mapping that would go here,

in the entitytypeconfiguraiton we currently have

```
public class RichPersonMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<RichPerson> {

...
this.HasKey(t => new { t.P_ID, t.Age });
...
this.HasMany(x => x.accounts)
               .WithOptional()
               .Map(/* WHAT GOES HERE */);

}
```

Comment: This may not be related to the answer, but what is the reason behind P_ID and Age begin primary keys for RichPerson?

Comment: sorry for the delay in replying you are absolutely right, it was a hair brained idea, have now reverted to using single primary keys everywhere and its working a treat ..